# Uncaught Error: https://127.0.0.1:9002 is not allowed to override this storefront. at webApplicationInjector.js:4

Tags: javascript, spartacus-storefront

I am integrating JS-storefront in smartedit and I get the following error. The loading wheel keeps spinning.

> Uncaught Error: https://127.0.0.1:9002 is not allowed to override
>   this storefront.
>       at webApplicationInjector.js:4

My storefront is running as per instructions here. https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/

Appreciate your comments here.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your problem here is about the difference between localhost:9002 & 127.0.0.1:9002 - conceptually those are the same from a human perspective.  But to a browser those are two independent URLs with no obvious relationship.

If you followed those documented instruction that you linked to, you will have setup the piece that includes:

```
data-smartedit-allow-origin="localhost:9002"
```

Therefore you should access it as https://localhost:9002